# mongoose suppressWarning option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the following warning in console and accordingly this is due to having a top level property as a 24 character hex string.

```
warn: mongoose: To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`. Set the `suppressWarning` option if you're trying to create a hex char path in your schema.
```

Where can I set suppressWarning option though?

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema try this:

```
const itemIdSchema = new Schema({
key: String
},{suppressWarning: true});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think they have fixed this bug later. I upgraded mongoose from v4 to v6 a few months back then and the warning was gone.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5587)